# Searching for the ratio in alloys

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two alloys A and B are composed of two basic elements. The ratios of two compositions of two basic elements in the two alloys are 4:3, 5:4 respectively. A new alloy X is formed by mixing the two alloys A and B in the ratio 3:2. What is the ratio of the compositions of the two basic elements  in alloy X?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything is clean and linear,

In Composition 1, A is 4/7, In 2, A is 5/9. So, if you mix A and B in the ratio 3:2, A will be  $$\frac{3}{5}\times \frac{4}{7} + \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{5}{9}$$ Similar computation for B.

Also, `linear-algebra` has a very different meaning. A better tag to use for this question is `precalculus` or `algebra`.